# When I user logging.config.fileConfig('log.conf') in python，it throws an error：ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handlers'

Tags: python, logging, handler

I want to use logging.config.fileConfig to load config file,but it throws an error：ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'handlers'. How do I change my code or config file ? Thanks.
This is my code：

```
import logging.config
import logging

# logging.handlers = logging.handlers
logging.config.fileConfig('log.conf')

logger = logging.getLogger('simpleExample')

logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warning('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

This is my config ：

```
[loggers]
keys=root,simpleExample

[handlers]
keys=fileHandler,consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=fileHandler

[logger_simpleExample]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=simpleExample
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
args=(sys.stdout,)
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter

[handler_fileHandler]
class=handlers.TimeRotatingFileHandler
args=('error.log', 'a')
level=ERROR
formatter=simpleFormatter

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Comment: You will need to import `logging.handlers` like you did with `logging.config`.

Comment: I had tried this ,but it also throw this error.

Comment: If the error is coming from the configuration file, the line `class=handlers.TimeRotatingFileHandler` may be the problem - you will need to use `logging.handlers` there instead of just `handlers`.

Comment: I had  used logging.handlers there instead of just handlers,and it throwd this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logging.handlers.TimeRotatingFileHandler'; 'logging.handlers' is not a package

Comment: I have found the reason. I had misspelled “TimeRotatingFileHandler”